# How to find all solutions to $f\star f=f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, convolution

I am trying to find all solutions to

$$f\star f=f$$ with $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I can solve this equation for $f\in L^1$ (and hence for $f\in L^1\cap L^2$). If I want a solution in$f\in L^2\setminus L^1$,
I know that we cannot directly use the Fourier transform with $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, since $f\star f$ only belongs to $L^2\cap L^\infty$.

I have tried to use an approximating sequence $f_n\in L^1\cap L^2$ with no success yet.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to use the Fourier transform?  It's well-defined for $f \in L^2$.

Comment: @NateEldredge The problem is that we do not have an explicit expression in $L^2$

Comment: @CalvinKhor If we want to use Fourier transform for this equation, the equality : $\hat{f\star f}=\hat{f} \star \hat{f}$ does not hold for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Maybe an idea could be to use a sequence $(f_n)_{n>0} \in L^1 \cap L^2$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$.

Comment: What is the context involving the question? It's good to put one, how you have tried it.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo I was asking what are the solutions of this functional equation in $L^2$. For instance the case $L^1$ is ok with the explicit expression but not in $L^2$. That is why I want to use a sequence $f_n \in L^1 \cap L^2$. For the sequence $f_n$ I, have the formula : $(\hat{f_n})^2= \hat{f_n}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor In general the equality $\widehat{f\star g}=\hat{f}.\hat{g}$ holds for $(f,g)\in L^1 \times L^1$ or $(f,g)\in L^1 \times L^2$ (see Young inequality for convolution). In the space $L^1 \cap L^2$ we have directly the Fourier-Plancherel expression.

Comment: @Maman Maybe now you can consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 3):

So it is given that $f*f=f$ with $f \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ . So in particular $f*f \in L^2(\Bbb R)$

Thus applying the Fourier transform on both sides, we have $(\hat{f}(\xi))^2=\hat{f}(\xi)$ for a.e. $\xi$ i.e. $$\hat{f}(\xi)(\hat{f}(\xi)-1)=0 \text{ for a.e. } \xi$$ Thus either $\hat{f}(\xi) \equiv 0 \text{ for a.e. } \xi \implies f \equiv 0 $ a.e.

Or, $\hat{f}(\xi) \equiv 1 \text{ for a.e. } \xi$ but then $\hat f \notin L^2(\Bbb R)$

So the only possibility left with $\hat{f}(\xi)(\hat{f}(\xi)-1)=0 \text{ for a.e. } \xi$ and $\hat f \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ is $\hat f = \chi_E$ where $E$ is some measurable set with finite, positive measure.But then $\hat f \in L^1(\Bbb R) \cap L^2(\Bbb R)$ thus you can apply inverse Fourier transform on that to obtain $$f(x)=\int_{\Bbb R} \chi_E(\xi)e^{i\xi x} d\xi=\int_{E} e^{i\xi x} d\xi \text{ a.e. } x \in \Bbb R$$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe As $f*f=f \in L^2(\Bbb R)$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe In general $L^2 * L^2 \hookrightarrow C_0$

Comment: Thanks for answering but we don't have necessary if $f,g\in L^2$ the expression : $\widehat{f \star g}(\xi) = \hat{f(\xi)}\hat{g(\xi)}$.

Comment: @Maman Of course we have! (Why else do you think there are 3 upvotes? LMAO) In fact it's a worthy exercise to do at least once. Hint: Use density of Schwarz functions